# Server 2008 slow home page load in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer

I have a problem with Internet Explorer for **all users**.

On startup the home page takes around 20-30 seconds to load. This includes servers such as the Domain Controller and Terminal Server.

However once the home page has loaded all pages from then on run fine. If you close and then reopen Internet Explorer the same thing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system are your clients using?  What version of Internet Explorer?  What is the home page set to?

I am having a similar problem, but only for Windows Vista / Windows 7 machines using IE8 (and probably IE7).  It only happens with our sharepoint 2007 homepage.  Windows XP machines have the same home page and work just fine (regardless of the version of Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 1):

It was rather simple once I found the solution - I simply unchecked the "Automatically detect Settings" under LAN Settings on the Connection Tab in Internet Explorer. This has fixed the issue.

I then used a registry change through Global Policy to push out these changes to every user. Problem is now solved site wide!

Comment: You're detected settings almost certainly point to a unreachable proxy. IE tries to reach the proxy for 30 seconds, times out and goes to direct connection mode. You should check your DNS, DHCP, and GPO settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the asp.net service isn't always running.  Once you visit the site, it automatically loads and then it'll be fine from there onwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I didn't check this but it could also reduce first page time.